# Android - Camera onPause in Service

Tags: android, service, camera, android-camera, onpause

I am developping an application which takes photos in a service. But as I understood what I saw in various post and docs, the Camera Service uses `onPause()` method from `Activity`. But as I want to use the camera in a service, which method is called ? Does `onPause()` is still called but in my `Activity` ?

Answer (score 0):

The camera service knows nothing about Activity onPause(), that's just part of the standard Activity lifecycle.

Using a camera in a background service is dangerous, as you will be denying access to the camera to whatever app is in the foreground. So if you are doing this, close the camera as soon as you are done taking a picture in your service.